# Remove function for binary search tree not working

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

```
else if (left == NULL) {
    Node *tempNode = new Node();
    tempNode = right;
    tempNode = right;
    tempNode->parent = parent;
    if (t < parent->data) parent->left = tempNode;
    if (t > parent->data) parent->right = tempNode;
    delete this;
    }
```

This is my code for remove fcn of a binary search tree when the parent has only one child. It deletes the node I'm looking to delete but also deletes everything that comes after it. Please help.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that. My bad. Yes, c++. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: What's `t`? Would look better if you can show us the entire function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to zero your own left and right pointers before executing `delete this`. Otherwise your left and right subtrees will get deleted too (assuming you've written your destructor properly).

And you need to account for the case `t == parent->data`, if it is possible; or else remove the redundant `t > parent->data` test and use `else`.

And there is certainly no need to allocate a `new Node()`. You are assigning the variable in the very next line. Don't write code like this.

It should be:

```
Node *tempnode = right;
right->parent = this->parent;
right = nullptr;
// etc.
```